# weird vertical shifting / jumping after scrolling in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, scrolling

just installed a fresh version of windows 7 64bit

and while using chrome, the scroll does some annoying jumping after the scrolling stops. (after stopping it will shift one line up and down couple times)

i've installed windows dozens of times and never seen this issue. I am using logitech revolutions mouse with set point driver suite, and can't find any settings there or in windows mouse that would address this.

it is not happening in Firefox which may indicate this is a chrome problem, but not seeing any scrolling options in chrome settings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was the smooth scrolling. i disabled it in set point mouse properties, and the problem went away.

as a bonus it also fixed my problem with google maps zooming, where slight wheem move would zoom enormous amounts.